# Cтандартная функция C++ возвращающая время в 10^(-3) или в 10^(-6) степени

Tags: c++, sfml

На данный момент проблема в функции void initGenerator(PRNG& generator). Которая вычисляет в течении одной секунды один и тот же seed. Существует ли стандартная функция C++ которая позволит вычислять новый seed каждую милли- или микросекунду?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;


constexpr unsigned BALLS_COUNT = 4;
const string WINDOW_TITLE = "Moving balls";
constexpr unsigned WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
constexpr unsigned WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

struct Ball
{
    CircleShape shape;
    Vector2f offset;
};

struct PRNG
{
    std::mt19937 engine;
};

void initGenerator(PRNG& generator)
{
    //cout << "initGenerator is started" << endl;
    // Используем время с 1 января 1970 года в секундах как случайное зерно
    const unsigned seed = unsigned(std::time(nullptr));
    generator.engine.seed(seed);
    cout << "seed == " << seed << endl;
}

// Генерирует индекс в диапазоне [0, size)
size_t random_index(PRNG& generator, int size)
{
    //cout << "random_index is started" << endl;
    // Создаём распределение
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, size - 1);

    // Вычисляем псевдослучайное число: вызовем распределение как функцию,
    //  передав генератор произвольных целых чисел как аргумент.
    return distribution(generator.engine);
}

void pollEvents(RenderWindow& window)
{
    Event event{};
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            break;
        default:
            break;  
        }
    }
}

float length(const Vector2f& value)
{
    return std::hypot(value.x, value.y);
}

float distance(const Ball& ball, const Ball& curr)
{
    return length(ball.shape.getPosition() - curr.shape.getPosition());
}

float dot(const Vector2f& left, const Vector2f& right)
{
    return left.x * right.x + left.y * right.y;
}

float sqr(float value)
{
    return value * value;
}

sf::Vector2f getSpeedAfterStrike(const Ball& first, const Ball& second)
{
    const Vector2f deltaSpeed = first.offset - second.offset;
    const Vector2f deltaPos = first.shape.getPosition() - second.shape.getPosition();
    return first.offset - deltaPos * (dot(deltaSpeed, deltaPos) / sqr(length(deltaPos)));
}

void update(vector<Ball>& balls, float deltaTime)
{
    constexpr float MAX_DELTA_TIME = 0.1f;
    deltaTime = std::min(deltaTime, MAX_DELTA_TIME);

    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        if ((ball.shape.getPosition().x + ball.shape.getRadius() >= WINDOW_WIDTH) || (ball.shape.getPosition().y + ball.shape.getRadius() >= WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        || (ball.shape.getPosition().x - ball.shape.getRadius() <= 0) || (ball.shape.getPosition().y - ball.shape.getRadius() <= 0))
        {
            ball.offset = -ball.offset;
        }
    }

    for (size_t fi = 0; fi < balls.size(); ++fi)
    {
        for (size_t si = fi + 1; si < balls.size(); ++si)
        {
            Ball& first = balls[fi];
            Ball& second = balls[si];
            if (distance(first, second) <= (first.shape.getRadius() + second.shape.getRadius()))
            {
                const Vector2f newFirstSpeed = getSpeedAfterStrike(first, second);
                const Vector2f newSecondSpeed = getSpeedAfterStrike(second, first);
                first.offset = newFirstSpeed;
                second.offset = newSecondSpeed;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        ball.shape.move(ball.offset * deltaTime);
    }
}

void redrawFrame(RenderWindow& window, vector<Ball>& balls)
{
    window.clear();
    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        window.draw(ball.shape);        
    }
    window.display();
}

void init(vector<Ball>& balls, PRNG& generator)
{
    const vector<Color> colors = {
        Color(128, 64, 255),
        Color(255, 64, 128),
        Color(128, 255, 64),
        Color(64, 128, 255)    
    };


    const vector<float> sizes = {
        40,
        40,
        40,
        40
    };    


    const vector<Vector2f> positions = {
        { 5* sizes.at(0), 5 * sizes.at(0) },
        { WINDOW_WIDTH - 3 * sizes.at(1), WINDOW_HEIGHT - 12 * sizes.at(1) },
        { WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 },
        { WINDOW_WIDTH - 3 * sizes.at(3), WINDOW_HEIGHT - 3 * sizes.at(3) }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < BALLS_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        initGenerator(generator);
        balls.at(i).offset.x = random_index(generator, 250);
        balls.at(i).offset.y = random_index(generator, 250);
        //cout << "balls.at(" << i <<").offset.x == " << balls.at(i).offset.x << endl;
        //cout << "balls.at(" << i <<").offset.y == " << balls.at(i).offset.y << endl << endl;
        balls.at(i).shape.setRadius(sizes.at(i));
        balls.at(i).shape.setPosition(positions.at(i));
        balls.at(i).shape.setFillColor(colors.at(i));
        balls.at(i).shape.setOrigin(balls.at(i).shape.getRadius(), balls.at(i).shape.getRadius());
    }
}

int main()
{
    Clock clock;
    ContextSettings settings;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode({WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT}), WINDOW_TITLE, Style::Default, settings);
    PRNG generator;
    vector<Ball> balls(BALLS_COUNT);

    init(balls, generator);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float deltaTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        pollEvents(window);
        update(balls, deltaTime);
        redrawFrame(window, balls);
    }
}
```

Comment: См. [chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/)

Comment: Можно использовать инструкцию rdtsc, она каждый так новое значение выдавать будет. Но я не знаю функцию стандартной библиотеки для нее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все начинающие программисты, когда стыкаются с генерацией случайных чисел, думают, что если вызывать инициализацию генератора чаще, то (псевдо)случайные числа будут более случайны и качественны. Но это не так. Числа будут в лучшем случае также (псевдо)случайны. А в большинстве случаев они будут менее (псевдо)случайны. И тут как раз и пытаются использовать более "качественный" генератор.

Что делать? Инициализировать таймер один раз при старте. И больше не нужно. Даже если очень сильно хочется.

Что делать, если случайность не достаточно случайна? Для начала почитать Кнута (второй том).

Comment: Ну не будем преувеличивать, не все... :) А вообще непонятно, откуда такая манечка берется.

Comment: все, все. Просто они по разному это скрывают. Есть, к примеру, ценители, которые арифметическими/бинарными операциями пытаются сделать (псевдо)случайное число более (псевдо)случайными.

Comment: Нет, все же, те, которые в программирование идут правильным путем, через математику - те такую ерунду не делают...

Comment: @Harry ну почему бы не делать `rand()<<16 + rand()` такое? Я как-то привык уже даже...

Comment: @pavel Я о seed'ах :) А кстати, вас не смущает, что один бит при этом в обычных реализациях - где RAND_MAX - это 2^15 - остается пустым?